# How to update and re-write a CGAL 3D mesh file

Tags: c++, graphics, mesh, cgal, graph-visualization

I am using CGAL to generate 3D mesh and I am modifying one of the examples provided by their website. All I have done are resetting vertices to new positions using set_point() function provided by the vertex_handle type. Now I want to write my updated mesh to a *.mesh file. I tried the following

```
std::ofstream medit_file1("out2.mesh");
CGAL::output_to_medit(medit_file1, c3t3);
```

from the code that the example code writes the original mesh file like this one:

```
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Mesh_triangulation_3.h>
#include <CGAL/Mesh_complex_3_in_triangulation_3.h>
#include <CGAL/Mesh_criteria_3.h>
#include <CGAL/Implicit_to_labeling_function_wrapper.h>
#include <CGAL/Labeled_mesh_domain_3.h>
#include <CGAL/make_mesh_3.h>
#include "implicit_functions.h"
// IO
#include <CGAL/IO/File_medit.h>
using namespace CGAL::parameters;
// Domain
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel K;
typedef FT_to_point_function_wrapper<K::FT, K::Point_3> Function;
typedef CGAL::Implicit_multi_domain_to_labeling_function_wrapper<Function>
                                                        Function_wrapper;
typedef Function_wrapper::Function_vector Function_vector;
typedef CGAL::Labeled_mesh_domain_3<K> Mesh_domain;
// Triangulation
typedef CGAL::Mesh_triangulation_3<Mesh_domain>::type Tr;
typedef CGAL::Mesh_complex_3_in_triangulation_3<Tr> C3t3;
// Mesh Criteria
typedef CGAL::Mesh_criteria_3<Tr> Mesh_criteria;
typedef Mesh_criteria::Facet_criteria    Facet_criteria;
typedef Mesh_criteria::Cell_criteria     Cell_criteria;
int main()
{
  // Define functions
  Function f1(&torus_function);
  Function f2(&sphere_function<3>);
  Function_vector v;
  v.push_back(f1);
  v.push_back(f2);
  // Domain (Warning: Sphere_3 constructor uses square radius !)
  Mesh_domain domain(Function_wrapper(v), K::Sphere_3(CGAL::ORIGIN, 5.*5.), 1e-6);
  // Set mesh criteria
  Facet_criteria facet_criteria(30, 0.2, 0.02); // angle, size, approximation
  Cell_criteria cell_criteria(2., 0.4); // radius-edge ratio, size
  Mesh_criteria criteria(facet_criteria, cell_criteria);
  // Mesh generation
  C3t3 c3t3 = CGAL::make_mesh_3<C3t3>(domain, criteria, no_exude(), no_perturb());
  // Perturbation (maximum cpu time: 10s, targeted dihedral angle: default)
  CGAL::perturb_mesh_3(c3t3, domain, time_limit = 10);

  // Exudation
  CGAL::exude_mesh_3(c3t3,12);

  // Output
  std::ofstream medit_file("out.mesh");
  CGAL::output_to_medit(medit_file, c3t3);
  return 0;
}
}
```

Above code is copied from "mesh_implicit_domains.cpp" from [here](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Mesh_3/index.html)
. But after I opened the new mesh file with visualization software, it just looks the same as the original one. I don't know what else should I do here(eg, like I should do updates to c3t3 too)?
I am new to CGAL, but I really have something on hand to be done in a short time, so a clear concrete answer like a code example would be really appreciated. Thank you guys.

Comment: Maybe you should present a code example, ideally put on gist.guthub.com

Comment: @AndreasFabri  I edited the post as you've suggested.

Comment: I tried to reposition a vertex far away but still sees no change in the new mesh file.

Comment: I don't see any setting of vertex coordinates in your sample code. Am I missing something?

Comment: An arguably easier method to access CGAL is via [pygalmesh](https://github.com/nschloe/pygalmesh). It's also easy to write the file using [meshio](https://github.com/nschloe/meshio).

Comment: Hey guys, I fixed it using a pointer to the triangulation of c3t3. c3t3.triangulation() merely returns another identical object of type Tr., not the original one.

Comment: @sloriot My mistake, I simply didn't include that part in the code for briefness, since I originally guess the mistake occurs in the last 3 lines of code in my example. Well, I finally managed to figured out what to do:).